# Como fazer uma consulta no banco de dados 10 dias pra frente e 10 dias pra trás da data atual?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hoje já consigo fazer a consulta de 10 dias atrás como mostra a consulta abaixo, só não estou conseguindo implantar os 10 dias a frente da data atual.

```html
SELECT 
  `vw_saldobancario`.`contaApelido`,
  `vw_saldobancario`.`tipoMovimento`,
  `vw_saldobancario`.`historico`,
  (
    vw_saldobancario.debitosPendentes + vw_saldobancario.debitos
  ) AS debitos,
  (
    vw_saldobancario.creditosPendentes + vw_saldobancario.creditos
  ) AS creditos,
  `vw_saldobancario`.`dataMovimento`,
  `vw_saldobancario`.`conta_bancaria_id`,
  IF (
    creditosPendentes > 0 
    OR debitosPendentes > 0,
    'SIM',
    'NAO'
  ) AS Pendentes 
FROM
  `vw_saldobancario` 
WHERE `dataMovimento`  BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -10 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()
  AND `conta_bancaria_id` = 3 
GROUP BY `idHistorico`
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se você pensa incluir data atual mais 10 a função é DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL value addunit). Não precisa incluir o sinal: DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)

Comment: Sim, mas essa não e a questão amigo e como eu faço pra ter além de 10 a frente também ter 10 atrás ??

Comment: WHERE `dataMovimento`  BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -10 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)

Comment: Era isso mesmo man, Obrigado!!

Comment: Que bom que te ajudei man!